# Prove that certain subset $M$ of $\mathbb R^4$ is a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, jacobian, submanifold

> Consider the subset $M\subset\mathbb R^4$ given by the equations:
> $$M\equiv \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> x^2+y^2-z^2-t^2=1\\
> -xt+yz=1
> \end{array}\right.$$
> Prove that $M$ is a smooth manifold.

My idea is to define the smooth map $f:\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^2$ given by:
$$f(x,y,z,t)=(x^2+y^2-z^2-t^2-1,-xt+yz-1)$$
It is well know that *if $J(f)$ has rank $2$ in $M=F^{-1}(0,0)$ then $M$ must be a 2-dimensional smooth manifold.*

Unfortunately, I am not able to find a regular submatrix of:
$$J(f)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
2x & 2y&-2z&-2t\\
-t&z&y&-x
\end{array}\right)$$
taking in count that $(x,y,z,t)\in M$.

Any help?

Comment: It could also be treated as the reciprocal image of $\frac12 i$ by transformation $(x-it)^2+(y+iz)^2$ (by considering real and imaginary parts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the two minors

$$J_{14}(f)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2x &-2t\\
-t&-x
\end{array}\right)$$

and

$$J_{23}(f)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2y&-2z\\
z&y
\end{array}\right)$$

Which has determinant $-2(x^2 + t^2)$ and $2(y^2+z^2)$ respectively. If both are zero, then $x=y=z=t = 0$, but $(0,0,0,0)$ is not in $M$. Thus either one of the above minors is invertible for all $(x, y, z, t)\in M=F^{-1}(0,0)$. Hence $(0,0)$ is a regular value of $F$.